# Flutter: Snackbar with OnPressed option

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the below code for Snackbar.

```
void _showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String message, Color color) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      backgroundColor: color,
      content: Text(message),
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
```

This is how am i calling it wherever required.

```
_showSnackBar(context,'Account created Successfully.',Colors.green);
```

It is working fine totally fine. I don't see any issues.

But now i need to add Onclick option in Snackbar.
Like below code.

```
action: SnackBarAction(
              label: 'Undo',
              onPressed: () {
                // Some code to undo the change.
              },
            ),
```

I am not sure how to add it and where to add it.

Please suggest.

**Edit:**
Little more explanation of what I want to achieve.

```
void _showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String message, Color color) {
```

how can i pass the parameters for OnPressed event? That's the issue i am getting.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote. I am not sure why it get downvoted. I think i have already provided the details. like what i have done and what is expected and not asking full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the following code:

```
    void _showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String message, Color color) {
        final snackBar = SnackBar(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
          backgroundColor: color,
          content: Text(message),
          action: SnackBarAction(
              label: 'Undo',
              onPressed: (){}
          )
        );
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
      }
```

You can find more info on SnackBar's here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars

Comment: Your answer is fine but not resolving my issue. As if you see my code i am calling it as a function and not sure how can i pass the parameters for OnPressed event.

Comment: @Ironic   Is this what you mean: void showSnackBar(
      BuildContext context, String label, Color color, SnackBarAction action) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(label),
      backgroundColor: color,
      action: action,
    );

    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be achived with:

```
SnackBar(
  content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
  action: SnackBarAction(
    label: 'Undo',
    onPressed: () {
      // Some code to undo the change.
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try your suggestion. Voted up.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any wanted parameters to your custom `_showSnackBar` method, and inside this method you can do whatever you want with these parameters.

As I see it:

```
    void _showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String message, Color color) {
            final snackBar = SnackBar(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
              backgroundColor: color,
              content: Text(message),
              action: SnackBarAction(
                  label: 'Undo',
                  onPressed: (){
                    print(color);
   /// do what you want with passed color or message
                   }
              )
            );
            _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
          }
```